# How do I move to a mouse coordinate from a string?

Tags: python, coordinates

I have the desired mouse coordinates which I would like to move to written in a string, but when I try to move it, I simply get:

```
(108, 119)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nope\Desktop\Coding\Python\mousemove.py", line 23, in <module>
mouse.move(xypose)
TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
[Finished in 330ms]
```

Here is my code:

```
import mouse
xypose = "(108, 119)"
xynoparentheses = xypose.replace("(", "")
xynoparentheses2 = xynoparentheses.replace(")", "")
print(xypose)
mouse.move(xypose)
```

Comment: Why did you write `xypose = "(108, 119)"` and not `xypose = (108, 119)`?

Comment: Because I need it to be in string format, plus it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Apparently you *don't* need it in string format but as two individual numbers.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate the string `'(108, 119)'` as the tuple `(108, 119)`.

Comment: I don't know why you can't just make it a tuple and cast it to string for whatever you need the string version for, but you certainly don't need the parens in the string.

Comment: I think it would help to know why you need it as a string; for instance, are you receiving it from user input? As currently presented, it's difficult to advise.

Comment: @Mario what? Did you comment in the wrong question by mistake?

Comment: @CrazyChucky I tried offered solutions in Google Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/) unsuccessfully once I installed the package via pip. There is no output. what is the problem with this package?

Comment: @Mario if you're having trouble installing Mouse, check the installation instructions in the docs. If that doesn't work, try searching on here or on Google. If all else fails, ask a new question rather than using the comments of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xypose` is a sting which contains `108, 119`. It might look like a list of two values but it is not. It is a string.

You need to split your string (`108, 119`) by comma and convert each element to `int` values, since most probably `move` expects 2 intgers.

```
import mouse
xypose = "(108, 119)"
xynoparentheses = xypose.replace("(", "")
xynoparentheses2 = xynoparentheses.replace(")", "")
xypose2use = map(int, xynoparentheses2.split(", "))
print(xypose2use)
mouse.move(*xypose2use)
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: also you can shorten code to `xypose2use = map(int, xypose.strip('()').split(', '))`

Comment: Ty! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is one way you can parse the numbers from your string. The below simply uses a `regex` to find all numbers, up to 6 digits long, and comprehensively include them in a `tuple` as an `int`.

```
import re

xy_str = "(100, 200)"
xy = tuple(int(n[0]) for n in re.finditer(r'\d{1,6}', xy_str))
    
mouse.move(*xy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separating it into two parts and `int()`-ing them separately, you can slice off the parentheses, then split it, map with int, and then convert to a tuple:

```py
import mouse
xypose = "(108, 119)"
xypose = tuple( # convert into tuple
        map(int, # map with int() to convert into numbers
                xypose[1:-1].split(", ") # Slice off the parentheses and split at comma
        )
    )
print(xypose)
mouse.move(xypose)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, as comment said.

```py
import mouse
import ast.literal_eval as e
xypose = "(108, 119)"
mouse.move(*e(xypose))
```